# Antialiasing option behaves weird (polygon edges visible in ContourPlot)

Tags: graphics, plotting

When I set the `Antialiasing` option in `Style`, I get the followings:

```
plot = ListContourPlot[
   Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 2, 0.05}, {j, 1.2, 2, 0.05}], 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["AvocadoColors"], Contours -> 10, 
   Mesh -> False, ImageSize -> 400];
Grid@{{
   Style[plot, Antialiasing -> Automatic],
   Style[plot, Antialiasing -> True],
   Style[plot, Antialiasing -> False]
   }}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For `Antialiasing -> Automatic`, everything is fine. Though `Antialiasing -> True` reveals polygon edges while still maintaining antialias on contourlines, frames, etc. `Antialiasing -> False` gives a plot where nothing is antialiased and polygon edges are not visible.

There is this thing written in the documentation for `[Antialiasing][1]`:

> With the default setting Antialiasing -> Automatic, choices are made to
>   optimize appearance on each type of computer system.

I would not say this is an optimal appearance. Can anyone tell me the logic/algorithm behind `Automatic` in this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe that forcing anti-aliasing renders the edges of the polygons with alpha transparency, and that where two of these adjoin there is a region that remains partially transparent, through which the background shows.  Example:

```
Style[plot, Antialiasing -> True, Background -> Magenta]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thanks for revealing it. Though I don't really understand why transparency of edges is involved in antialiasing.

Comment: @Istvan, I believe it is one of the standard methods when compositing, and it probably makes more sense for live graphics than oversampling does.