# Inconsistent GraphicsRow behaviour

Tags: graphics, antialiasing

During the debugging of my previous [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/381/antialiasing-option-behaves-weird-polygon-edges-visible-in-contourplot) (somewhat related), I encountered this strange behaviour: when the global option `Antialiasing` is set to `True` in **Option Inspector**, the following code gives **non-antialiased** plots (observe e.g. frames):

```
GraphicsRow@{
  ListContourPlot[
   Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 2, 0.05}, {j, 1.2, 2, 0.05}], 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["AvocadoColors"], Contours -> 10, 
   Mesh -> False, ImageSize -> 400],
  ListDensityPlot[
   Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 2, 0.05}, {j, 1.2, 2, 0.05}], 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["AvocadoColors"], Mesh -> False, 
   ImageSize -> 400]
  }
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The next input is from the same notebook, same session, the only difference is that `GraphicsRow` only contains one plot object. Result is **antialiased** (visible polygon edges are of no concern here, see [other](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/381/antialiasing-option-behaves-weird-polygon-edges-visible-in-contourplot) post).

```
GraphicsRow@{ListContourPlot[
   Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 2, 0.05}, {j, 1.2, 2, 0.05}], 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["AvocadoColors"], Contours -> 10, 
   Mesh -> False, ImageSize -> 400], ""}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Question**

Is it a bug of `GraphicsRow`?

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: @ragfield FWIW I see the same behavior on mma7/win7.

Comment: I use Win7/Mma8. I should add that on the OSX/Mma8, while non-antialiasing is not that obvious due to some screen smoothing, still the two `GraphicsRow` objects produces different outputs. The first two plots seem to be non-antialiased, the second has the visible polygon edges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GraphicsRow puts both plots into one GraphicsBox, which means they have to be rendered together.  Since the DensityPlot contains VertexColors it has to be rendered (on some platforms) using the 3D graphics renderer, whose support for Antialiasing is highly hardware dependent.

ContourPlot output normally renders with a 2D graphics engine.  DensityPlot normally renders with a 3D graphics engine.  When you group the two together (via GraphicsRow in this case) it forces them both to render with the 3D graphics engine, and that causes the ContourPlot to have a slightly different appearance.

Take a look at this example, containing only the ContourPlot.  This code forces the ContourPlot to be drawn with a 2D renderer (in my case Quartz, since I'm using a Mac) in one window and a 3D renderer (OpenGL) in another window.  Observer the difference in appearance (at full size):

```
g = ListContourPlot[
   Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 2, 0.05}, {j, 1.2, 2, 0.05}], 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData["AvocadoColors"], Contours -> 10, 
   Mesh -> False, ImageSize -> 400];

CreateDocument[g, CacheGraphics -> False, 
  "NotebookRenderingEngine" -> "Quartz"];

CreateDocument[g, CacheGraphics -> False, 
  "NotebookRenderingEngine" -> "OpenGL"];
```

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide some detail of why the rendering is substantially different in GraphicsBox?

Comment: Just interested to know what the differences are - my eyes are struggling to see any difference between the images on my machine.

Comment: If you view the image at full size (right-click > Open in New Window) you can tell the one on the left (Quartz) is antialiased, while the one on the right (OpenGL) is not.  Since it has been scaled down to fit in the webpage they both appear antialiased.

Comment: My Windows WM 11.3 does not recognized the option NotebookRenderingEngine option.. 
 Any idea why?

Comment: @JoseEnriqueCalderon By "not recognized" do you mean the syntax highlighting is red, or do you mean it doesn't appear to have any effect? What are you trying to accomplish? This is not a documented option and is therefore subject to change without notice. I only used it here to demonstrate the difference between the antialiasing behavior using 2D drawing vs. 3D drawing. This option probably wouldn't be useful for actually trying to accomplish anything.

Comment: @ragfield syntax highlighted .  I copy pasted to my WM 11.3 run in Win10.  When looking documentation returned nothing for NorebookRenderingEngine option. What version you are running?

Comment: @JoseEnriqueCalderon The option is not documented (it doesn't appear in the documentation, and it's existence and behavior can change at any time), which is why syntax highlighting flags it. It's probably not something you want to be using.

Comment: @ragfield  where you get this then?  IS this a legacy item of from a input package?

Comment: @JoseEnriqueCalderon I am aware of the undocumented option because I am one of the developers of Mathematica. Are you just curious about this specific option or are you trying to solve a specific problem?