# Pattern that matches colors

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, color

Suppose I'm writing a function that takes a color as a parameter; for example:

```
drawShape[color_] := Graphics[{Style[Disk[], color]}];
```

But if the caller inputs an invalid color, bad things happen:

[image: Bad]

So I want to use a pattern to define `drawShape` only for values that are actually colors. Conceptually,

```
drawShape[color_Color] := ...
```

The problem is that unlike (say) `List`s, `Integer`s, `Real`s, `Complex`es, or `Graphics`es, color objects do *not* share a `Color` head. That is,

```
In[1]:= Red // Head
Out[1]= RGBColor
In[2]:= Hue[0.5] // Head
Out[2]= Hue
In[3]:= GrayLevel[0.5] // Head
Out[3]= GrayLevel
In[4]:= CMYKColor[0, 1, 1, 1/2] // Head
Out[4]= CMYKColor
In[4]:= Opacity[0.5, Purple] // Head
Out[4]= Opacity
In[5]:= Transparent // Head
Out[5]= GrayLevel
```

So that won't work. I also don't see any `ColorQ` function, with which I could write `drawShape[color_ ? ColorQ] := ...`.

**How can I write a pattern that matches any valid color object?** Is there a more robust way than just testing for each of these heads?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Original method

```
colorQ = Quiet @ Check[Blend @ {#, Red}; True, False] &;

colorQ /@ {Red, Hue[0.5], GrayLevel[0.5], CMYKColor[0, 1, 1, 1/2], Opacity[0.5, Purple]}
```

> ```
> {True, True, True, True, True}
> ```

```
colorQ /@ {17, 1.3, Pi, "not a color", {1, 2, 3}, Hue["bad arg"]}
```

> ```
> {False, False, False, False, False, False}
> ```

You would use: `drawShape[color_?colorQ] := . . .`

---

Inspired by kguler's comment this might also be formulated as:

```
colorQ = Quiet[Head @ Darker @ # =!= Darker] &;
```

Or:

```
colorQ = FreeQ[Quiet @ Darker @ #, Darker] &;
```

**Edit:** `Darker` works on entire `Image` and `Graphics` objects and therefore the two forms immediately above will incorrectly return `True` in these cases.  `Blend` solution is still valid.

---

### Version 10 update and analysis

In version 10 there is a built-in function for this: [`ColorQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorQ.html)

> `ColorQ[color]` yields True if color is a valid color directive and False otherwise.

A bit of spelunking reveals that the inner definition of this function is (contexts stripped for clarity):

```
iColorQ[args_?(ColorDirectiveQ[Head[#1[[1]]]] &), opts_] := 
  NumberQ[Quiet[ToColor[args[[1]], XYZColor][[1]]]]
```

This is very similar to my own method, however the inner definition of `ColorDirectiveQ` omits `Opacity`:

```
iColorDirectiveQ[args_, opts_] := 
 TrueQ[Quiet[
   MatchQ[args[[1]], 
    GrayLevel | RGBColor | CMYKColor | Hue | XYZColor | LUVColor | LABColor | LCHColor]]]
```

This means that the function will return `False` for e.g. `Opacity[0.5, Purple]` where mine returns `True`.

Comment: Nice. I particularly like that it can distinguish between `Opacity[0.5, Purple]` and `Opacity[0.5]`.

Comment: Neat! (`Darker@#;True` or `Lighter@#;True` work as well.)

Comment: @kguler Good idea!

Comment: @kguler I added a couple of other versions based on your comment.

Comment: That's very useful (+1), I should put one of these tests into my answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2638/245) as well.

Answer (score 10):

I think that the following catches all color heads.

```
Clear[test];
test[x : (_CMYKColor | _Hue | _RGBColor)] := "good"
test[else_] := "bad"
```

Let's try it

```
test[Red]
(* Out: "good" *)

test[red]
(* Out: "bad" *)
```

Comment: `test[GrayLevel[0.5]]`

`"bad"`.

Obviously you can just test the heads against all you think of, but that's not robust if you forget one or if Wolfram adds another.

Comment: Note that this will fail for malformed or incomplete color directives, e.g. `RGBColor[1]`. +1 nevertheless, but see my answer for a more robust method.