# Is there a way to logically test an optional color input inside a module?

Tags: graphics, color, scoping

Suppose I create a `Module` that is expected to return a graphic that I will later use in a plotting procedure (e.g., with `Show[]`).  One of my inputs is an optional input that I want to test (to prevent breaking etc.) inside the `Module`.  This optional input is supposed to be a color (e.g., `Red`).  I am running into several issues that I think should not be issues.  Suppose the name of the optional input is `lcolor` for the discussion below.  Here is a very simple analogous example to what I refer.

```
test[lcolor_: Red] := Module[{}, Red == lcolor]
test[RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]
test[Red]
test[Blue]
```

1. I can perform a boolean test `Red == RGBColor[1,0,0]` which results in `True`.  However, if I try `Red == RGBColor[0,0,1]`, Mathematica just returns the input rather than `False`.  Can anyone explain why this is?  I tried using `Evaluate` to force it to compare the two, but received the same result.
2. Is there an equivalent/parallel to something like `NumberQ` for colors in Mathematica?  I want to test this input to make sure it is a color that will be accepted by `Directive` or `Graphics3D`.

   - To try and test the input, I first tried the following example (which worked on the command line):  `(Context[lcolor] == Context[Red]) && (Attributes[lcolor] == Attributes[Red])`.  However, if I define `lcolor` as `Red` it turns into `RGBColor[1,0,0]` inside the `Module`, which causes both `Context` and `Attributes` to return errors.  However, simple checks like that discussed in (1) do not work, so I am left confused.  I even tried to wrap the inputs for `Context` and `Attributes` in `ToExpression[ToBoxes[], StandardForm]` and `MakeExpression[ToBoxes[], StandardForm]`, but neither method worked.
   - Then I tried just forcing `lcolor` to be an integer and compared it to a list of possible integers, but this is very restrictive.  I do not want to explicitly write out (nor can I) every possible color that Mathematica can handle.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I guess you want a [pattern that matches colors](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15431/484).

Comment: in version 10 there is [ColorQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorQ.html)

Comment: @kguler Unfortunately, I have v8.0.1 and do not want to spend another several hundred dollars for a personal license.  Is there any kludge/hack that could approximate `ColorQ` in v8?

Comment: @RahulNarain oh thanks, I think the pattern matching link you supplied might work.  I will check that out to see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My concerns have been mostly addressed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15431/pattern-that-matches-colors).  The correct answer that works is given by:

```
colorQ = Quiet @ Check[Blend @ {#, Red}; True, False] &;
```

which can be implement in either of the following methods:

```
colorQ /@ {Red,Hue[0.5],GrayLevel[0.5],CMYKColor[0,1,1,1/2],Opacity[0.5,Purple],blah}
{True, True, True, True, True, False}
colorQ[Red]
True
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `SameQ` (===):

```
test[lcolor_: Red] := Module[{}, Red === lcolor]

test /@ {RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Red, Blue}
```

> {True, True, False}

For a full explanation read the `Details` sections for `Equal` and `SameQ`

Comment: First thanks for the clarification.  The answer you supplied works for comparison to a specific color.  Is there a general test to determine if the user actually supplied an acceptable color?  I only used my `test[]` module as an overly simplified example.  Is there a way to test if the user entered something like `Red` (or `Green` or `Blue` etc.) or a graphics directive like `RGBColor` (or `Hue` or `CMYKColor` etc.)?  Also, why does `Module` convert `Red` to `RGBColor[1,0,0]`?