# Extracting RGB color code from a plot

Tags: plotting, color

I have let *Mathematica* to draw a plot of some functions written as below:

```
fplot = Plot[{Sinh[1/t],
   4 Cosh[1/(4 t)],-2 (Sinh[0.5/(2 t)]), -2 (Sinh[1/(2 t)] + Sinh[1/t])}, {t, 0.01, 1.5},

PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.008]}, {Thickness[0.008]}, {Thickness[
  0.008]}, {Thickness[0.008]}}
, PlotRange -> {-10, 10}, Frame -> True]
```

> [image]

I tried `fplot // Options` but I cannot access the RGB codes of colors in the plot. How can I extract the RGB codes which *Mathematica* has by default used in this plot?

Comment: The plotting functions are countable and even finite in MMA, so a more viable approach is to just know, what is used. For the normal `Plot` function the colors are given by `ColorData[97, "ColorList"]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following is a universal solution which extracts RGB color values assigned to the `Line` primitives of a plot generated by built-in plotting functions of *Mathematica* **10**:

```
Cases[fplot, {___, c_Directive, __Line} :> 
   ColorConvert[c, RGBColor], Infinity] // InputForm
```

> ```
> {RGBColor[0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798, 1.], RGBColor[0.880722, 0.611041, 0.142051, 1.], 
>  RGBColor[0.560181, 0.691569, 0.194885, 1.], RGBColor[0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179, 1.]}
> ```

The above pattern is found by inspection of internal structure of `Graphics` objects produced by such functions as `Plot`, `ListLinePlot`, `ParametricPlot`, `ContourPlot` etc. of *Mathematica* **10.4.1**. It is tested with plots generated by all listed functions and works quite reliably. If you encounter a case when it fails, please let me know.

For previous *Mathematica* versions more involved approach based on the [`colorQ`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15434/280) function of [Mr.Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) is necessary. For example, for version 8.0.4 the following should be sufficiently general (but in many situations it will lose `Opacity` specification):

```
colorQ = Quiet@Check[Blend@{#, Red}; True, False] &;
Cases[fplot, {Longest[___], c_?colorQ, ___, __Line} :> ColorConvert[
   If[Head[c] =!= Directive, c, Last@Cases[c, _?colorQ, Infinity]]
   , RGBColor], Infinity]
```

> ```
> {RGBColor[0.2472, 0.24, 0.6], RGBColor[0.6, 0.24, 0.442893], 
>  RGBColor[0.6, 0.547014, 0.24], RGBColor[0.24, 0.6, 0.33692]}
> ```

This solution should work the same way with versions 9 and 10. The problem with `Opacity` is difficult to avoid because in version 8 `ColorConvert` cannot work with `Directive`.

---

For inspection of the structure of `Graphics` I recommend my [shortInputForm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280) function:

[image: screenshot]

An advanced description of the *Mathematica* graphical programming language can be found in these threads:

- [Structure of Graphics (esp. those produced by Plot, ListPlot, etc.)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32712/280)
- [How to examine the structure of Graphics objects](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32716/280)

---

If you wish to find the *default* colors used by the built-in plotting functions, you should consult with the following threads:

- [What are the standard colors for plots in Mathematica 10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54629/280)
- [How to access new colour schemes in version 10?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54486/280)
- [What are the standard colors for plots in Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5391825/590388)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer and your explanation

Answer (score 3):

```
Cases[fplot, RGBColor[x_, y_, z_] :> {x, y, z}, Infinity]
```

> {{0.368417, 0.506779, 0.709798},
>      {0.880722, 0.611041, 0.142051},
>      {0.560181, 0.691569, 0.194885},
>      {0.922526, 0.385626, 0.209179}}

Comment: `Normal` does nothing in your solution (it doesn't affect colors in any way). And your solution will fail if the color is specified not as `RGBColor` but as `GrayLevel`, `Hue`, `XYZColor` or other color model. In many situations it will also return nonworking colors which are present on the low level but do not affect the display.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyPopkov. I didn't actually notice that `Normal` is still there. I agree with you about the other colors. It just a old fashioned way I use and wanted to share :)