# Rearrange colors in BarChart

Tags: list-manipulation, color, charts

I have the following code which produces an animated bar chart.

```
counts = 101;
names = Sort[{"name01", "name02", "name03", "name04", "name05"}];
nbars = Length[names];

maxRandomNumber = 1;

data = Array[0 &, {nbars, counts}];

Do[data[[All, i]] = data[[All, i - 1]] + 
 RandomInteger[maxRandomNumber, nbars];, {i, 2, counts}];

Animate[BarChart[data[[All, i + 1]], ImagePadding -> All, 
  Frame -> True, ChartStyle -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
  PlotRange -> {{0, nbars + 1}, {0, 1.1*Max@Flatten@data}}, 
  ImageSize -> 600, 
  ChartLabels -> Placed[names, Axis, Rotate[#, -Pi/2] &], 
  LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Panel[#1, FrameMargins -> 0], Above] &),
   FrameLabel -> {{"votes", ""}, {"names", ""}}, 
  ChartLegends -> names], {i, 0, counts - 1, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, AnimationRepetitions -> 1, 
 DefaultDuration -> 20, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Now I want to sort the bars by decreasing number:

```
Animate[BarChart[Sort[data[[All, i + 1]], Greater], 
  ImagePadding -> All, Frame -> True, ChartStyle -> "BlueGreenYellow",
   PlotRange -> {{0, nbars + 1}, {0, 1.1*Max@Flatten@data}}, 
  ImageSize -> 600, 
  ChartLabels -> Placed[names, Axis, Rotate[#, -Pi/2] &], 
  LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Panel[#1, FrameMargins -> 0], Above] &),
   FrameLabel -> {{"votes", ""}, {"names", ""}}, 
  ChartLegends -> names], {i, 0, counts - 1, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, AnimationRepetitions -> 1, 
 DefaultDuration -> 20, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

How can I keep in the second animation the same legend colors for the different names (this is the case, as in animation 1) but in the sorted bar chart these colors have to be rearranged corresponding to the counts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't want to delete any part of your codes to make a MWE, but since there are lots of options in them I'll go step-by-step to highlight what I have done.

First, your first `Animate`, in its entirety:

```
counts = 101;
names = Sort[{"name01", "name02", "name03", "name04", "name05"}];
nbars = Length[names];

maxRandomNumber = 1;

data = Array[0 &, {nbars, counts}];

Do[data[[All, i]] = 
    data[[All, i - 1]] + RandomInteger[maxRandomNumber, nbars];, {i, 
   2, counts}];

Animate[pl = 
  BarChart[data[[All, i + 1]], ImagePadding -> All, Frame -> True, 
   ChartStyle -> "BlueGreenYellow", 
   PlotRange -> {{0, nbars + 1}, {0, 1.1*Max@Flatten@data}}, 
   ImageSize -> 600, 
   ChartLabels -> Placed[names, Axis, Rotate[#, -Pi/2] &], 
   LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Panel[#1, FrameMargins -> 0], 
       Above] &), FrameLabel -> {{"votes", ""}, {"names", ""}}, 
   ChartLegends -> names], {i, 0, counts - 1, 1, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, AnimationRepetitions -> 1, 
 DefaultDuration -> 20, AnimationRunning -> False]
```

The only change so far is that I gave a name, `pl` to the `BarChart` (right after `Animate[`).

[image]

Second, I extract the colors from `pl` (credit to [Sumit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/113835/22013)):

```
colors = Cases[pl, RGBColor[x_, y_, z_] :> RGBColor[x, y, z], 
   Infinity][[-nbars ;; -1]]
```

---

The colors could be also obtained with `ColorData`:

```
colors = Table[ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][i], {i, 0, 1, 0.25}]
```

as pointed out by [Feyre](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7312/feyre).

---

I keep them as `RGBColor` so I can use them without further alterations.

In the second, *sorted*, animation, I use `ChartStyle -> colors[[Ordering[#, All, Greater]& @ data[[All, i + 1]]]]`. The reasoning is that I use `Ordering` to get the initial (i.e., before you apply `Sort[..., Greater]`) order of `data[[All, i+1]]`; let's call it `order` for a moment. Then I rearrange the `colors` according to the same `order` - basically, I do `colors[[order]]`. Finally, I directly feed the colors to the `ChartStyle`:

```
Animate[BarChart[Sort[data[[All, i + 1]], Greater], 
  ImagePadding -> All, Frame -> True, 
  ChartStyle -> 
   colors[[Ordering[#, All, Greater] &@data[[All, i + 1]]]], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, nbars + 1}, {0, 1.1*Max@Flatten@data}}, 
  ImageSize -> 600, 
  ChartLabels -> 
   Placed[names[[Ordering[#, All, Greater] &@data[[All, i + 1]]]], 
    Axis, Rotate[#, -Pi/2] &], 
  LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Panel[#1, FrameMargins -> 0], Above] &),
   FrameLabel -> {{"votes", ""}, {"names", ""}}, 
  ChartLegends -> 
   names[[Ordering[#, All, Greater] &@data[[All, i + 1]]]]], {i, 
  0, counts - 1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 AnimationRepetitions -> 1, DefaultDuration -> 20, 
 AnimationRunning -> False]
```

[image]

Notice that I also changed `ChartLabels` and `ChartLegends` from `names` to `names[[order]]`.

---

**EDIT:** `ChartLegends` had to be changed from `names` to `names[[order]]` for the colors to match the names. This alters the ordering of the displayed names, i.e. `name03` is first, instead of `name01`. To have it in order I produce a `SwatchLegend` (which is used by `BarChart` by default, so it will look consistent):

```
legend = SwatchLegend[colors, names]
```

[image]

Then just type `ChartLegends -> legend`.

Comment: This is exactly the solution ... perfect, thank you for your help and explanation.

Comment: `Cases[pl, RGBColor[x_, y_, z_] :> RGBColor[x, y, z], Infinity]` is an odd bit of code; the rule appears superfluous.  Consider `Cases[pl, _RGBColor, Infinity]` instead, or `Cases[pl, _RGBColor?ColorQ, Infinity]` for robustness.

Comment: How can I keep the `ChartLegends` with the orginal colors and alphabetical order unchanged during each evaluation step?

Comment: @lio See the edit.

Comment: I learned a lot from you ...

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: also for your proposal we need `[[-nbars ;; -1]]` after `Cases[pl, _RGBColor, Infinity]`. That is probably the only solution to access the colors?

Comment: @lio I would use `ColorData` myself, as already shown in the answer above.  For more of my thoughts on extracting style information from plots see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/123155/121