# Remove grid background in figures saved as PDF

Tags: grid-layouts, pdf-format

Whenever I save a figure as a PDF I seem to get a grid that's visible in the background. This doesn't show up when I view the figure in mathematica. How do I get rid of the grid?

Here's how the PDF looks like[image]

Here's how a similar figure looks in mathematica
[image: No grid in mathematica]

This shows up even if I plot something really simple like RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 5, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]

Comment: `Export["image.pdf", 
 RegionPlot[x^2 + y^2 < 5, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  ColorFunction -> LightBlue]]` This seems to work

Comment: related/possible duplicate Q/A: [Avoiding white lines inside filled area in RegionPlot exported as PDF or PS](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2629/125)