# An issue in Exporting 2D contour plot as .PDF file

Tags: plotting

I have a contour plot  (`Windows-10, Mathematica 12.3`)

For example;

```
 p = ContourPlot[
  Evaluate[Re[
    Product[x + I y - (a + I b), {a, -2, 2}, {b, -2, 2}]]], {x, -3, 
   3}, {y, -3, 3}, ColorFunction -> Hue]
Export["exampleplot.pdf", p]
```

When I zoom in on the plot, it looks like there are (six-pointed) star shapes on **some lines.** (Please see the following figure.)

[image]

I think this makes the shape look worse. **How to get rid of them?**

**P.S.** I want to export the plot as high-quality figures in the format `.pdf` or `.eps.` I don't want to export as `.png` or `.jpeg` or to `Antialiased` it.

Comment: same issue: [Spikes on the edge of a ContourPlot exported as PDF](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/151820/125)

Comment: It's not a solution. The suggestion removes the interior part of my plot.