# Exporting ParametricPlot to .pdf

Tags: plotting, graphics, export, pdf-format

I am trying to use ParametricPlot to produce some nice looking images of regions bounded by various curves. However, the plots look weird when I export them to .pdf. For example, I have tried plotting two disks, one using the Graphics primitive and the other using ParametricPlot. This is the code:

```
Show[Graphics[{Disk[]}], ParametricPlot[{3 + r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {r, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
PlotStyle -> {Black, Opacity[1]}, BoundaryStyle -> Black, Mesh -> None]]
```

The result exported to .png looks as expected:

[image]

However, the result exported to .pdf produces some weird behavior:

[image]

What exactly is going on here? How do I export the disk produced by ParametricPlot to .pdf so that it retains the look of the disk produced using the Graphics primitive?

Comment: Some additional information: I am using Mathematica 8.0.

Comment: The PDF export in older versions is extremely buggy. Is there a reason you need to export to pdf?

Comment: @mmeent: No particular reason at the moment. However I have used such plots when writing papers before and in such cases this would be helpful. Anyway, I have now found [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/avoiding-white-lines-inside-filled-area-in-regionplot-exported-as-pdf-or-ps?rq=1) which seems to be about the same problem. In fact, adding `EdgeForm[Black]` to the options of PlotStyle helps a lot. (It still looks slightly weird when using various levels of zoom in Adobe Acrobat, but I think I can live with that.)