# How to overlap ContourPlots

Tags: plotting, color

I have the following functions, which are

```
x^2 - y^2
```

and

```
2 x y
```

of two variables which represent the real and imaginary part of a complex function $f(z)$. I want to show that the contour lines of the two function intersect perpendicularly. I have the two `ContourPlot`

```
cp1 = ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   Contours -> 20,
    PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
cp2 = ContourPlot[2 x y, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, Contours -> 20,
    PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
```

[image]

What I would like to do is to overlap the two plots keeping the color between the contour lines, but with opacity so that I can see the contours below intersecting normally the contours above.

I partially achieved this result with:

```
cp1 = ContourPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
   Contours -> 20,
    PlotLegends -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"];
cp2 = ContourPlot[2 x y, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, 
    Mesh -> None, 
    (*ContourShading->None, *)

   ColorFunction -> Function[f, Opacity[.5, ColorData["Rainbow"][f]]], 
    Contours -> 20,
    PlotLegends -> Automatic
    ];
Show[cp1, cp2]
```

[image]

but as you can notice there's a strange grid below the fist plot...

## EDIT (completness):

I'm using mathematica 11.1.0.0

[image]

Comment: No strange grid for me. I'm using version 11.1. What are you using?

Comment: 11.1 as well... Can't understand what it is...

Comment: Also for me it works perfectly (V 10)

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2629/avoiding-white-lines-inside-filled-area-in-regionplot-exported-as-pdf-or-ps/2630#2630

Comment: Try `ContourPlot[ReIm[(x + I y)^2], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> {ColorData[97, 1], ColorData[97, 2]}]`

Comment: Adding `Style[Show[cp1, cp2], Antialiasing -> False]` Following the link for Michael E2 may work.

Comment: @J.M. this will plot only the lines, that is not what I really whished...

Comment: @Hugh even with the anti-aliasing I still have the grid, plus it has very bad resolution...

Comment: I can reproduce it on V11.1.1 (Mac).  -- I'm more interested in what sort of background you really want.  I don't see why blending the two (opacity = 50%) is worth it.

Comment: I understand, on Grapher, if you overlap the two colorised level set you obtain a fancy effect which help you visualise the growing rate or the decay... I was hoping there was something similar on Mathematica.

Comment: Do you still get the same effect if you modify the second `ColorFunction` to `ColorFunction -> Function[f, Append[ColorData["Rainbow", f], 0.5]]`?

Comment: Yes, still there... I can't understand why it works for you but not for me... doesn't it sound strange?

Comment: This works for me: `Show[cp1, cp2 /. EdgeForm[] -> EdgeForm[Directive[Opacity[0]]]]`.  Does it for you?

Comment: That's the reason for asking for your OS; I don't see this on Linux.

Comment: Darn! There are faint edge lines from the underlying plot...I can't hardly see them and missed them until I exported to PNG.

Comment: @MichaelE2 wow that worked for me, thanks a lot... what was the problem due to? If you make a complete answer I'l give you the correct one ;) Thanks again anyway

Comment: Ok, no, I didn't zoomed... there are still the grid lines, but now are very thin, so the outcome is acceptable for me, even if it would be good not to have them at all

Comment: I posted an answer, but maybe someone will fix `cp1`.  (The same trick does not work on it.)

Comment: The option `Exclusions -> {x^2 + y^2 == 0.0001}` also fixes the kink at the origin in `cp1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Show[cp1, cp2 /. EdgeForm[] -> EdgeForm[Opacity[0]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The lines in the OP come from the edges of the polygons forming the contour shading.  The above trick makes them invisible.

(The OP said this is acceptable, but I see faint, dark lines from the edges of the polygons of `cp1`.)

Comment: @opisthofulax Try adding the option `MaxRecursion -> 3` to the `ContourPlot[]` for `cp1`.  Stationary points are singular points for `ContourPlot`, in that the contour through one is usually not a single, simple curve. Normally you can't fix it, but you can make it smaller. Increasing `PlotPoints` and/or `MaxRecursion` is how you do might that.

Comment: `Exclusions -> {x^2 + y^2 == 0.0001}` also works.