# Anti-aliasing with the multiple-object form of Polygon?

Tags: graphics, antialiasing

Observe:

```
rand = RandomReal[1, {4, 3, 2}];

Graphics @ Polygon @ rand
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graphics[Polygon /@ rand]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I am losing anti-aliasing when I use the multiple-polygon syntax form of `Polygon`.  Yet it is possible for *Mathematica* to apply AA as can be shown with:

```
Style[
 Graphics @ Polygon @ rand,
 Antialiasing -> True
]
```

(Incidentally this `Style`-applied AA does not copy with Szabolcs's Image Uploader but the in-Notebook appearance is identical to the second output above.)

- Why am I losing anti-aliasing here?
- Is there a system option to turn it on, and with what caveat?

Comment: It seems with antialiasing on, you get seams between adjacent polygons. It's in the end of possible issues in the `Polygon` docs. So probably it assumes that by default, with the multiple-polygon syntax form it's more important to avoid seams for adjacent polygons and with the several distinct polygons antialiasing is more important. Just an idea

Comment: Also, setting the `Antialiasing->True` globally instead of `Automatic`, fixes this, but I have no idea what other sideeffects it has

Comment: Maybe one could add the "undocumented" tag.

Comment: @Rojo Antialiased polygons don't join properly and will create artefacts in e.g. a `ListDensityPlot`, try `ListDensityPlot[RandomReal[1, {20,3}]]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems with antialiasing on, you get seams between adjacent polygons. 
It's at the end of the *possible issues* section in the `Polygon` documentation page.

So probably it assumes that by default, with the all-in-one-polygon syntax form (one `Polygon` head for multiple polygon representations) it's more important to avoid seams for adjacent polygons, and with the multiple-`Polygon`-syntax, antialiasing is more important.

Functions such as `ContourPlot` or `ListDensityPlot`, that use `Polygon` to render it's results, use this all-in-one syntax to save space, and require the polygons to join well, so by default antialiasing is off.  See [Antialiasing option behaves weird (polygon edges visible in ContourPlot)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/381/121) for an example of what can happen with anti-aliasing.  You could always set the option `Antialiasing` to `True` instead of `Automatic`, either at global or notebook or cell level, but you will suffer the consequences when using one of these functions.

Answer (score 16):

`Antialiasing` can be used as a directive inside `Graphics`:

```
Table[Graphics[{Antialiasing -> aa, Polygon[rand]}], {aa, {True, False}}]
```

[image]

Comment: That's a very unusual syntax!

Comment: I didn't know this (+1) but it still requires an additional step, and it still doesn't explain what I'm seeing.  Any further comment?

Comment: It's good to know (+1), but @Mr.Wizard's `Style` syntax allows the same thing and seems more consistent.

Comment: Only that globally forcing `Antialiasing -> True` would have negative consequences for some scenarios (possibly depending on platform.)

Comment: Brett, is it accurate to say that built-in functions rely on this form of `Polygon` *not* using antialiasing to prevent [this artefact](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/381/121)?

Comment: The difference is due to the behavior of Antialiasing->Automatic (see the documentation for Antialiasing).  The behavior of Automatic is not defined (and could change).  The current behavior is effectively True for a single polygon and False for a multi-polygon (even it if only has one item).

Comment: Cool! BTW, `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Antialiasing -> False}]` also works.