# Finding the centroid of a disk in an image

Tags: graphics, image-processing

I got about 100 images of the sun and have to find the centre of the star in the images. I have binarized the images and used `ComponentMeasurements`to find the `Centroid` and the `EquivalentDiskRadius`.  So far so good, but I have noticed that in Mma's calculation the centroid appears to have the tendency to gravitate slightly towards the right bottom edge. I first thought that is due to the fact the the disk of the sun is a slight ellipse due to objective imperfection etc but I can replicate the effect with an image I create in Mma using the `Disk` command.

```
disk = Rasterize[Graphics[{Disk[]}], ImageResolution -> 100];
ndisk = 1 /. 
  ComponentMeasurements[
   ColorNegate@disk, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}];
pdisk = 1 /. 
  ComponentMeasurements[disk, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}];
Show[{disk, 
  Graphics[{{Red, Circle[ndisk[[1]], ndisk[[2]]]}, {Green, 
     Circle[pdisk[[1]], pdisk[[2]]]}}]}]
```

The result of the centroid calculation depends also on whether the disk is positive or negative. What am I missing here or how could I fit a circle to a binary image which contains a **slightly** distorted disk?

[image: Result of the above Show command]

**Edit:**
Based on some of the answers I simpified the input image by using an even and an odd sized array.

```
m = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
   {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},{0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
   {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};

k = {{0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0},{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},{0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},{0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0}};

circ = 1 /. 
  ComponentMeasurements[m, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}]
(* {{3.5, 3.5}, 2.03421} *)

circ2 = 1 /. 
  ComponentMeasurements[k, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}]
(* {{3., 3.}, 2.76395} *)

Show[{ArrayPlot[m], 
  Graphics[{Red, Thick, Circle[circ[[1]], circ[[2]]]}]}]
Show[{ArrayPlot[k], 
  Graphics[{Red, Thick, Circle[circ2[[1]], circ2[[2]]]}]}]
```

Gives the results below. ComponentMeasurements finds the right centre in both cases what is off is the Circle that I draw over it. Look at the sizes of the small triangle the circle cuts off the black squares.

[image: ArrayPlot 1]

[image: ArrayPlot 2]

Comment: Would a simple correction of the effect help? If yes, then you could try something like
`Show[{disk,Graphics[{{Red,Circle[ndisk[[1]],ndisk[[2]]]},{Green,Circle[pdisk[[1]]+ndisk[[1,1]]-pdisk[[1,1]],pdisk[[2]]+ndisk[[1,2]]-pdisk[[1,2]]]}}]}]`

Comment: Thanks everyone for your valuable input. I am convinced that 'ComponentMeasurement' delivers the right result but the circle I draw to visually inspect the result is slightly off. This offset disapears when I enlarge the plot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the shift of the circle with respect to the disk is at least partially due to antialiasing effects. Compare for example:

```
disk = Binarize@Rasterize[Graphics[Disk[]]]; 
ndisk = 1 /. ComponentMeasurements[ColorNegate@disk, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}];

Show[{disk, Graphics[{{Red, Antialiasing -> True, Circle @@ ndisk}}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

with

```
Show[{disk, Graphics[{{Red, Antialiasing -> False, Circle @@ ndisk}}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How come an option can be inserted in a list of directives and primitives? Is this some undocumented usage, or did I just miss something from the documentation?

Comment: @IstvánZachar I don't think it's documented. I came across this usage [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7417/46)

Comment: @Heike Interesting effect. For some reason I didn't see the effect when I tried it. The binarized image of the sun has however no antialiasing.

Comment: @Matariki I was referring to the influence of antialiasing on the circle drawn on top of the binarized image, not of the image itself.

Answer (score 7):

Compare:

```
l = Rasterize[Show[Graphics[{Disk[{1, 1}, 10], Disk[{20, 20}, 10]}]]];
ComponentMeasurements[ColorNegate@l, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}]
ComponentMeasurements[l, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}]
```

[image]

`ComponentMeasurements` does not work for `black` objects ... they are not components ...

Comment: Yes, that's what I suspected when I tried it for various objects, however the documentation isn't mentioning this. It only hinds at it in its examples.So the algorithm object search needs the objects to be 0 to find them. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>I feel the doc page for ComponentMeasurements contains the solution:</strike>

> Position, area, and length measurements are taken in the standard
>   image coordinate system where position {0,0} corresponds to the
>   bottom-left corner, x runs from 0 to width, and y runs from 0 to
>   height.

You are counting whole pixels and `ComponentMeasurements` measures pixel positions. In this system, the center of the bottom left pixel is at {1/2,1/2}.

I have been looking somewhat closer to Heike's answer to bring out the differences caused by anti-aliasing better.

Without anti-aliasing:

```
disk = Rasterize[Graphics[{Antialiasing -> False, Disk[]}], ImageSize -> 61];
ndisk = 1 /. ComponentMeasurements[
    ColorNegate@disk, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}];
pdisk = 1 /. ComponentMeasurements[disk, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}];
Show[{disk, Graphics[{{Red, Circle[ndisk[[1]], ndisk[[2]]]}, 
     {Green, Circle[pdisk[[1]], pdisk[[2]]]}}]}, 
 Method -> {"ShrinkWrap" -> True}, ImageSize -> 610]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With anti-aliasing:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Both circles seem to be good fits to the disks *as they are rasterized*, but clearly rasterizing and anti-aliasing *both* introduce some asymmetries.

Comment: I understand that but shouldn't I still expect the circle to be in the middle of the component when I plot it where `ComponentMeasurements` deems the `Centroid` to be?