# Derive a smooth circle with cusp from an image

Tags: image-processing

[image]

### question 1 get the center

---

(*sample data*)

`sample` is the black circle with cusp.

```
 (*Input 1 ==< *)
 sample = Binarize[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7isS.png"]]
```

> ```
> (*Output CellExpression, You can copy to Notebook or just Skip*)
>  \!\(\*GraphicsBox[TagBox[RasterBox[CompressedData["1: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"], {{0, 271}, {278, 0}}, {0, 1},ColorFunction->GrayLevel],BoxForm`ImageTag["Bit", ColorSpace -> Automatic, Interleaving -> None],Selectable->False],BaseStyle->"ImageGraphics",ImageSizeRaw->{278, 271},PlotRange->{{0, 278}, {0, 271}}]\)
> ```

```
 (*Input 2 ==< *)
pts0 = PrincipalComponents@N@Position[ImageData[sample], 0];
{length = pts0 // Length, 
radius = EuclideanDistance[#, {0, 0}] & /@ pts0 // Mean,
center = Mean@pts0 // N // Chop, 
g1 = Graphics[{Point[pts0], {Red, Thick, circleNew = Circle[center, radius]}}]
}
```

> ```
> Output result see picture ==> :)@@
> ```

I do not like this, I' d like the red circle overlap the black circle.

### question 2 get the cusp.

---

Thought 1:

Put one locator in the cusp and drag it to along the diameter (from cusp point to center), and the `circleNew` will go to the center.

Maybe need interpolation, ie something `BezierCurve` or `BSplineCurve.`.

Thought 2:

Go on ImageProcessing, directly make `circleNew` (smooth except the place of cusp) overlap the balck circle.

Maybe here we can directly `Fit` one curve with one function?

```
 (*Input 3 ==< *)
 Pruning[Thinning[ColorNegate[Erosion[sample, 1]]]]
```

> ```
> (*Output CellExpression, You can copy to Notebook or just Skip*)
>  \!\(\*GraphicsBox[TagBox[RasterBox[CompressedData["1:eJztnMtu00AYhWcQC3bs2PMo8AjlCVoJtkgFCfXtSVtTcjm2ZzyX/3Y+qRfXdnLOZ8/ISZp8fvh59+NdSunXh9O3u/s/Xx4f75++vT8tfH36/f3hedXHnNKn0xcxQH5DOokezl3Qy0LeXIxCvuJmvUQoAd76l00dZ7IczzT55peivRY1PrU0H22HWnqMAFejqOP1h5uLmREdjHsZdlztehl7qhsdSONDm9My50gam3unJrWhZfrhs3C6SERUr0UmoGYtgnOf3mlXOpb0/QM0HCsFES5RkkdJjAU1aRTNL2qCvKIijTInSYUWBRFuEM8kHgAifP7qlJJEveibUs4QyqbaSRLSotxJEkmoX8r8jNpHz8LUS10jTl6ZlNWUk1lWbDlJcwKbk8KXplYYHdqklNGpbUoZnNuqlKHJ7UoZmN2ylGHpbUuhFcyQ/NalDGlgX8qADh6kdG/hQ0rnHl6k9G1CK2NvSpp+VRxJ6VfGlZRedZxJ6VPInZQelRxKae/kUUp7K59WWms5tdLWy6uUpmZ+pTR08yzlcDvfUg728y7lWENa6bWPMeorBpBS3zGClPqWtNK+uVnqekaxUvmxQaNSaKOmaBgpNU3jSKnoGklKeVtaOb6ZF2gFUtQ3mpSyxvGsFFQOKGW/c0Qpu6VDStlrHVPKTu2gUrZ7R5VCK5it5nGtbFWnlep1vqEVCIcQZLV7ZCmr5UNLoRUIrUBW6ge3stI/uhUoILwUWoHQCgIYoBRagdAKglYQtIK4VUAptIK5cUApiVYwHEEIWkHQCoLzCoJWINcWaOWFvLEUF1pB5NWFyOSV32NDKwhaQdAKglYQtIKgFQStIGgFQSsIWkHQCoJWELSCoBUErSBoBUErCFpB0AqCVhB8jh9BKwhaQdAKgq+oImgFkTcXo0IrCFpB0AqA/wGGoBUErSBoBUErCFpB0AqCVhC0AuC7GwB8exCCVhC0AuA73xH89BUAFhBdC60gaAVBK4CV+rRS9fcY0AqCVhCr7UNroRXAendaqVvjn43ucbVsNQ9rZbN4VCvbvWnlyGqn7LYOqWW/dEAtBZXjWSlpHM5KWeFoWgr7xtJS2pZW2jb0AK0gystG0kIrgJqqcbRUNY2ipa4nrfTY3Cq0AqhuGUJLfckAWg5U9G/lUEPvWg72863laDta6bmfCY6X86yloZtfLS3NvFrJbcV8amlu5VFLh07+tHRp5E1Lpz7OtNAKoFsbV1r6lXGkpWMVP1a6NvGipXMPJ1p613ChpXsJD1YGdLCvZUgD61oG5betZVh6y1oGZrerZWhyo1oan5Dcv/2xNz+G8aENapkRefTZ2J1JeW1pmZbWkpaJWQ1pmRnVipbJk6ANLdNTWtAikFG9FplLCOVapOKp1iIXTq8W0QtwrVqEc2WNj4o0ZFIQ4RIdgXSdL4rCMAlESxgtORZUxFE0ehYUBFIQ4YYsOuvK3vs2YsHUGnlB4pBpPk3+w+e/MDOfQTYjZWJWQ06eOeQl58o5wpiUdOThUb74UXIPlXegg7pP8Xjbumw3o07SMiQKN73YreB2j2ZSQlH+q402S5s38kLem0XRyrXN7Z8ll6y2wSvyOanArVFWGpUU9ajjH+hYO65bwfWYkM6jCwohhATjL3IdCrM="], {{0, 271}, {278, 0}}, {0, 1},ColorFunction->GrayLevel],BoxForm`ImageTag["Bit", ColorSpace -> Automatic, Interleaving -> None],Selectable->False],BaseStyle->"ImageGraphics",ImageSizeRaw->{278, 271},PlotRange->{{0, 278}, {0, 271}}]\)
> ```

[image]

Comment: Can you include your data?

Comment: Looks like this could help: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27007/find-radii-of-concentric-circles-in-image

Comment: @CoreyKelly data is the top black circle image

Comment: You have over 1000 reputation points. I think it's time that you take some time and learn how to properly format your code with markdown.

Comment: @m_goldberg ha, how about this edit. Welcome to give me suggestions.

Comment: I recommend you read [this meta-post](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/871/instructions-for-reviewers). It will give an idea of what kinds of formatting is desired by the community.

Comment: @m_goldberg ok, I'll read that.

Comment: I formatted your code once again. I hope you will study what I did and learn from it. The most important reworking was adding spaces and making line breaks in the proper places to improve the code's readability.

Comment: @m_goldberg thanks, I'll learn that.

Comment: What's the {0,0}?

Comment: @HyperGroups People will not be notified if you comment in the question (even if you use `@` — it does nothing inside questions and answers). Please comment here to respond individually to users (if you wish to). Re: the temp question — images exist indefinitely on SE servers.

Comment: @rm-rf  well,I learned that.

Comment: @cormullion now {0,0} is just the original point. In previous code I forgot `PrincipalComponents`.

Comment: @m_goldberg I'm learning formatting in SE, thanks for your suggestions. Sometimes my codes were copied to SE with my ragged programs (so many bugs). Sorry for some badly formatted codes in SE. And welcome to edit (or point out) my English errors as well as other mistakes (I'm learning English too, so I typed so many words :)).

Comment: @rm-rf If I uploaded/inserted images in one post/answer, and then I deleted the post or deleted the image links in the post. How long will the images be deleted in the SE's server?

Comment: @HyperGroups the images will be kept forever. For this reason it is not a good idea to upload large numbers of images or ones that are not really important.

Comment: @OleksandrR. OK,

Answer (score 8):

```
i1 = ColorNegate@ Opening[Binarize@Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VEuj.jpg", 1];
ct = 1 /. ComponentMeasurements[FillingTransform@i1, "Centroid"];
r = Mean[EuclideanDistance[ct, #] & /@ PixelValuePositions[i1, 1]];
Show[i1, Graphics[{Thick, Red, Circle[ct, r]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Late to respond for struggling with so many questions. I like it. @@ any suggestion for question2

Comment: @HyperGroups Re:your second question. The problem is that you're not imposing any constraints, so the "cusp" could be anything. You could propose  a cusp "model", some constraints, anything to thin down the infinite possibilities

Comment: Ok, I'll edit after I've done some continued work.

Answer (score 6):

Since the binary image a little noisy, the easiest thing is to Dilate it a bit to make it one connected component.

```
img = Dilation[ColorNegate[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7isS.png"]], 1]
```

[image]  [image]

Now we can use ComponentMeasurements to find the desired properties:

```
ComponentMeasurements[img, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}]

{1 -> {{139.859, 131.044}, 68.0123}}
```

So the center is about {139.859, 131.044} and the radius is 68.0123. Approaching it this way gives this circle:

```
Show[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/z7isS.png"], 
   Graphics[{Thick, Red, Circle[{139.859, 131.044}, 2 68.0123]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: ha, nicie.
I think put one slider in the cusp and drag to fit the whole circle is one way.
And you can think my question 2  @@

Comment: I might approach it this way: define an ideal version of the cusped circle. First, locate the best real circle like above to find the approximate center and radius. Then correlate your cusped circle with the image, once for each possible rotation. When you get the highest correlation, you will have the proper orientation of the cusped circle.

Answer (score 6):

Cusp detection using information from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27013/6849), and following the code from @belisarius' answer:

Transformation of the image to polar coordinates:

```
maxRadius = r + 10;
polar = ImageTransformation[i1, 
ct + {Cos[#[[1]]], Sin[#[[1]]]}*#[[2]] &, {360, maxRadius}, 
DataRange -> Full, 
PlotRange -> {{0, 360 \[Degree]}, {1, maxRadius}}]
```

result: [image: polar circle]

Then we find the position of the peak:

```
diff = Mean[Flatten[Position[#, 1]]] & /@ 
Transpose[ImageData[polar]];
cusp = Mean[Flatten[Position[diff, Max[diff]]]]
```

> 272

Display the detected cusp:

```
Show[i1, Graphics[{Thick, Red, Circle[ct, r], Green, 
Arrowheads[Large], 
Rotate[Arrow[{ct + {r - 50, 0}, ct + {r, 0}}], 
cusp Degree, ct]}]]
```

[image: arrow pointing to cusp]

Comment: nice, I should take time to read that post, welcome to move on.

Comment: seems @somebody in Answer and Post will not really notify somebody, rm-rf told me yesterday.