# Detecting an ellipse in a glaucoma photo

Tags: image-processing, fitting

For glaucoma diagnosis it is common to determine a "cup to disk ratio" which compares the diameter of the optic disk (VDD) and optic cup (VCD). The optical disk is visible as a circular red feature (red channel) and the optic cup shows up as a yellow circle (green channel). How can I calculate the diameter ratio between optic disk and optic cup?

I am able to detect the optic disk with canny edge detection, but I have not found a way to calculate the cup to disk ratio. How might I do that?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide sample images (without labeling) for experimentation?

Comment: Is your question more about how to automatically find the ellipse pattern in an image? or about fitting an ellipse at a starting point in an image? or more about calculating the size of the ellipse? Please provide a minimal example.

Comment: You may also check this answer for ellipse fitting. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25589/how-can-i-detect-an-ellipse-in-a-photo?rq=1

Comment: how about calculating the diameter between optic disk and optic cup? sorry my first question is not complete. i have already detect the optic disk with canny edge detection, but i have not found a way to calculate the diameter of optic disk and optic cup. How might I do that?

Comment: @kirma - Additional info and test images for glaucoma and related eye problems: [optic-disc.org](http://optic-disc.org/)

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 27):

Fitting an ellipse:

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7HJk.jpg"];
lineByCenter[center_, semi_, angle_] := Rotate[Line[{#1 - #2, #1 + #2}], angle, #1]&
                                                                       [center,{0,semi}]
sa    = 1 /. ComponentMeasurements[ Binarize@i, "SemiAxes"]
angle = 1 /. ComponentMeasurements[ Binarize@i, "Orientation"]
bbc   = Mean /@  Last /@ ComponentMeasurements[ Binarize@i, "BoundingBox"] // First
Show[i, Graphics[{Thick, White, Rotate[Circle[bbc, sa], angle, bbc],
                          Blue, lineByCenter[bbc, sa[[1]], angle + Pi/2],
                         Green, lineByCenter[bbc, sa[[2]], angle]}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**edit**

In your previous and now closed question you asked for a yellow "cup" and a red "disk".The problem is that the "cup" barely resembles a same-center ellipse, so you need to define some additional criteria.Look:

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7HJk.jpg"];
s = ChanVeseBinarize[i, "TargetColor" -> {Yellow, Red}];
ImageMultiply[i, ColorNegate@s]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**edit2**

[After some googling](http://www.jaypeejournals.com/eJournals/ShowText.aspx?ID=854&Type=FREE&TYP=TOP&IN=_eJournals/images/JPLOGO.gif&IID=77&isPDF=NO) I got convinced that the "cup" isn't really constrained to be a co-centered ellipse and the relevant parameters for the diagnosis/prognosis  aren't just size measurements, but also the relative position of both components:

[image]

Comment: what this is code for matlab? because im using matlab. can you give example using matlab code

Comment: @indraginanjarA.T This site is specific for Mathematica. You may post Matlab questions at http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: @indra, it's not our fault that you didn't bother to check that you were asking at an appropriate site.

Answer (score 18):

If you need more precise calculation you may check [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42613/detecting-the-radius-of-an-incomplete-circle?rq=1).

```
cm = ComponentMeasurements[Binarize@img, "BoundingDiskRadius"]
ct = 1 /. ComponentMeasurements[Binarize@img, "BoundingDiskCenter"];
Show[img, Graphics[{Thick, White, Circle[ct, cm[[1, 2]]]}]]
```

> {1 -> 63.4933}
>
> [image]