# Detecting and measuring an ellipse in a glaucoma photo?

Tags: image-processing

I've tried the solutions given in [How to find a circular object in the image glaucoma](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/99578/how-i-can-detect-ellipse-in-a-glaukoma-photo)? to detect the ellipse, but the detection results are not quite what I wanted.

In glaucoma we have a cup to disk ratio terms in which I must looking for calculate between the diameter of the optic disk (VDD) and optic cup (VCD). optical disks showed with a red circle (red channel) and optic cup showed with a yellow circle (green channel). how about calculating the diameter between optic disk and optic cup? sorry my first question is not complete. i have already detect the optic disk with canny edge detection, but i have not found a way to calculate the diameter of optic disk and optic cup. How might I do that?

[image: This is one example of an image glaucoma]

Comment: You posted a very similar question a few hours ago. This version of the question will probably be closed as a duplicate, but it does contain more detail and is better formed than your first version. I would suggest that you edit your original question by adding the details, links, and formatting that you have here to that one.