# How to fit implicit function based on an image in mathematica?

Tags: functions, image-processing, fitting

I know how to make a plot given a function, but I don't know how to get implicit function based on an image.

For example, I have the image shown below (thumbnail):

[image: graph]

Full size image import:

```
Import @ "https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLkeC.png"
```

I want to find the math function within it. It seems to be an ellipse, but what is a good way to get the function that plot as this ellipse?

Comment: Please show us the code you evaluated to get the image shown above. Add it to your question by making an edit to it.

Comment: Simon says this is the answers to your question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17780/8070

Comment: @Sumit, I read this post,but that method cannot get implicit function.And I cannot open Michael Trott's 3 post.

Comment: Note that the is not a unique function that has the boundary of the shape as zero-set.

Comment: Perhaps these Q&A are closer to your question: [(25589)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25589), [(99578)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99578)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Along the same line, I first binarize the image to obtain the ellipse, and rotate the image to get the correct origin of the pixel coordinates (we should recall that the pixel coordinates origin are at the left top corner):

[image]

```
imgbw = Binarize[ImageRotate[img, 270 Degree],Method -> {"BlackFraction", 0.99}];
elip = N@Position[ImageData@imgbw, 1];
```

Now, we fit the best ellipse by means of [51491](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51491/fitting-points-to-tilted-off-center-ellipse):

```
lin = {#1^2, #1, #2, 2 #1 #2, #2^2} & @@@ elip;
lm = LinearModelFit[lin, {1, a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}];
pa = lm["BestFitParameters"];
w[x_, y_] := pa.{1, x^2, x, y, 2 x y} - y^2;
ContourPlot[w[x, y] == 0, 
{x, 200, 400}, {y, 200, 500}, ContourStyle -> {Black, Dashed}, 
Epilog -> {Red, , PointSize[0.003], Point[elip]}]
```

[image]

$w[x,y]=-3.06274 x^2-y^2+1192.22 x+152.71 y+1.829648 xy-196494=0$

Answer (score 3):

lhere is a function which returns an implicit function such as the equation of an ellipse.

```
functionThatReturnsImplicit[image_] := Module[
                                             {img,edgeCoordinates,lin},
              edgeCoordinates = PixelValuePositions[EdgeDetect[image],1];

              lin = {#1^2, #1, #2, 2 #1 #2, #2^2} & @@@edgeCoordinates;
              lm = LinearModelFit[lin, {1, a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}];

              pa = lm["BestFitParameters"];
              w[xx_, yy_] := pa.{1, xx^2, xx, yy, 2 xx yy} - yy^2;
              w[x, y] == 0
              ]
```

---

for instance

```
     image = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLkeC.png";
```

---

> ```
>    functionThatReturnsImplicit[image]
> ```
>
> > > ```
> > >    -197019. + 1190.93 x - 3.05173 x^2 + 157.116 y + 1.81471 x y - y^2 == 0
> > > ```

[image]

Comment: Your function `functionThatReturnsImplicit` doesn't use its argument `image`...

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov thanks I will edit it, my bad

Answer (score 1):

Yet another approach:

```
img = Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLkeC.png";
{center, sa, angle} = 
  1 /. ComponentMeasurements[AlphaChannel@img, {"Centroid", "SemiAxes", "Orientation"}];
Show[Binarize[img], Graphics[{Blue, Thick, Dashed, Rotate[Circle[center, sa], angle]}]]
```

> [image: output]

```
m = TransformedRegion[Ellipsoid[center, sa], RotationTransform[angle]][[2]];
ellipseEquation = Expand[({x, y} - center).Inverse[m].({x, y} - center) - 1] == 0
```

> $0.000349686 x^2-0.000207989 x y-0.136216 x+0.000114855 y^2-0.0181534 y+22.5165=0$

```
Show[ContourPlot[Evaluate@ellipseEquation, {x, 200, 400}, {y, 200, 500}], 
 Graphics[{Red, Thick, Dashed, Rotate[Circle[center, sa], angle]}]]
```

> [image: output]