# extract line from position data

Tags: graphics

I got a picture like this, and what I want to do is to extract lines from the picture.

[image: borrenan]

what I have done now is

```
img = Import["http://euler.nmt.edu/mathwiki/images/e/ef/Borromean.png"]
PixelValuePositions[img, Blue, 0.5] // Point // Graphics
```

from which I get a list of positions of the blue curve like this:

[image]

so my question is , how do I get a Line from the postion data I get above?
what I want to get is not a circle function, but a list of points in good order.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking - the result of `PixelValuePositions` *is* a list of positions of the "points".

Comment: Vectorize the image first to PDF for example via [online.rapidresizer.com](http://online.rapidresizer.com/tracer.php), then import that to Mma.

Comment: @rasher,but with `PixelValuePositions` I get a list of unordering points, what I want is like this `Line[{p1,p2...pn}]`

Comment: @tintin `FindCurvePath` can make the ordering.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are over 2700 points and because they fill out a thick region, there is no real order to them.  It seems to me to get a single line, one would want to approximate the image by lines first.  One way is to use [`Thinning`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thinning.html).

```
img = Import["http://euler.nmt.edu/mathwiki/images/e/ef/Borromean.png"];
comp = MorphologicalComponents @ Thinning[ColorNegate @ Binarize[img]];
splice[{list1_?VectorQ, list2_?VectorQ}] /; 
   First@list1 == First@list2 := Join[Reverse@list1, Rest@list2];
splice[lists_] := Join @@ lists;

Graphics[
 Table[
  {Hue[c/6 - 0.1], With[{pos = Position[comp, c]},
    Line[pos[[
       splice @ FindCurvePath[pos]
       ]]]]},
  {c, 6}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Update:  It happens in this case that [`FindCurvePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindCurvePath.html) splits the first three lines into two components with the same starting point; the fourth into two disjoint components; and the rest are just one line.  When I first posted, I had forgotten to check all of them.  The update fixes how they are spliced together.  Some smoothing may obtained by skipping some points:

```
splice[FindCurvePath[pos]] ~Part~ (3 ;; -3 ;; 3)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Another way is to fit a circle:

```
circle = FindFit[
  Transpose[Append[Transpose[#], ConstantArray[0, Length @ #]]] &@
   PixelValuePositions[img, Blue, 0.5], (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 - r^2,
  {a, b, r}, {x, y}]
(*
  {a -> 95.864, b -> 97.5503, r -> 89.9539}
*)

Graphics[{
  PixelValuePositions[img, Blue, 0.5] // Point,
  Red, Circle[{a, b}, r] /. circle
  }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can use the `circle` data to generate a `Line` if desired.

---

There is also the methods found in [Derive a smooth circle with cusp from an image](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27017/derive-a-smooth-circle-with-cusp-from-an-image)

Comment: thanks so much, the first part is exactly what I want

Comment: @tintin  You're welcome and thanks for the accept. You might be interested the modification I made, which I think is an improvement.

Comment: nice answer, nice update, it works

Answer (score 3):

Without going to morphological manipulations, a quick way that might get you what you need (it's not super clear in the op) might be (uses the second image in your question in `img2`):

```
Needs["ComputationalGeometry`"]
pp = PixelValuePositions[img2, Black, 0.5];
curvelines = pp[[ConvexHull[pp, AllPoints -> True]]];
Graphics[{Line[curvelines]}]
```

[image]