# Detection of object in defocused microscope image

Tags: image-processing

This image is taken with an microscope:

[image]

Image adjustment:

```
ImageAdjust[image, {1, 1, 0.4}]
```

[image]

In the center one can see the edge of an defused approximately circular shaped object.

**How can I measure the center of the "circle"?**

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bimage-processing%5D+detect+circle

Comment: This answer seems to work out of the box: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27013/242