# Antialiasing of horizontal lines

Tags: graphics, antialiasing

Consider the following graphic:

```
g = Graphics[{Circle[], Table[Line[{{-1, i}, {1, i}}], {i, -1, 1, 0.2}]}, ImageSize -> 150]
```

[image: fuzzy]

(You may need to look [directly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAxyK.png) at the image because stackexchange seems to munge them).

You will note that the first and fourth lines from the top are quite crisp, while the third line is particularly fuzzy.  This is because in the antialiasing process, the first and fourth line end up on a row on pixels, while the third is split between two rows.

If we turn antialiasing off:

```
Style[g, Antialiasing -> False]
```

[image]

([direct link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGEWV.png))

We get all the lines nice and crisp, but of course the circle gets the jaggies.

What I'd like to do is to be able to adjust any horizontal (or vertical lines), so that they are antialiased to a single row (or column) of pixels.  Everything else, including angled lines would remain as is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use different settings for `Antialiasing` for different graphics primitives if you wrap each with `Style`:

```
 g2 = Graphics[{Style[Circle[], Antialiasing -> True], 
 Table[Style[Line[{{-1, i}, {1, i}}], 
 Antialiasing -> False], {i, -1, 1, 0.2}]}, ImageSize -> 250]
```

[image]

Comment: You don't even need `Style`; [this weird syntax](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7417/121) works: `Graphics[{Antialiasing -> True, Circle[], Antialiasing -> False, 
  Table[Line[{{-1, i}, {1, i}}], {i, -1, 1, 0.2}]}, ImageSize -> 250]`  (`Antialiasing -> True` could actually be omitted here but I leave it for illustration.)

Comment: @Mr.W, weird indeed.

Comment: This is quite nifty.  My new favourite rule is: `Line[n : ({{a_, _}, {a_, _}} | {{_, b_}, {_, b_}})] -> {Antialiasing -> False, Line[n]}`.  The next challenge is to make it work with arrows.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard that is unusual syntax. how did you figure that out?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Haven't you heard about `RandomOptions[]`? :D

Comment: @Mr.W, @Mike, fwiw the same syntax seems to work in other places where a graphics directive is expected: For example, `Plot[...,PlotStyle->(Antialiasing->False)]` or `Plot[..., Mesh->{2},MeshShading->{Antialiasing->True,Antialiasing->False}`, or `Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{GrayLevel[0.5], Antialiasing -> True, Thickness[0.02]}],...]` etc.

Comment: Jut read Bretts answer that Mr Wizard linked to. Missed that Q&A at the time. I wonder what other options work like directives?