# How to draw Graphics3D items with straight border lines?

Tags: graphics3d, antialiasing

I want to make a `Polygon` with straight border lines. For that purpose I wrote the following code, but it doesn't show straight borders.

```
Graphics3D[{Style[Polygon[{{20, 0, 10}, {50, 0, 10}, {50, 0, 25}, {20, 0, 25}}],
  Lighting -> {{"Ambient", LightBlue}}]}, Boxed -> False, RotationAction -> "Clip"]
```

How can I make a polygon with straight lines?

[image]

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198/131

Comment: You can switch the antialiasing quality of Preferences->Appearance->Graphics to Highest but beware as it might make graphics display unresponsive for higher resolution graphics.

Answer (score 7):

The Antialiasing quality dialog in Preferences offers an adjustable setting (if you have appropriate hadware, see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200/89)):

[image: anti aliasing dialog]

You can compare the differences between the two extremes in the following screen shots:

```
Graphics3D[
 Polygon[{{20, 0, 10}, {50, 0, 10}, {50, 0, 25}, {20, 0, 25}}], 
 Lighting -> {{"Ambient", LightBlue}},
 Boxed -> False,
 RotationAction -> "Clip"]
```

No Antialiasing:

[image]

Highest quality:
[image]

They're not as different as you might expect. The results are probably very hardware and operating-system specific.

Answer (score 4):

From a related Q/A [Antialiasing of horizontal lines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14543/125):

```
 Row[Graphics3D[{Antialiasing -> #,
 Polygon[{{20, 0, 10}, {50, 0, 10}, {50, 0, 25}, {20, 0, 25}}]},
 Lighting -> {{"Ambient", LightBlue}}, Boxed -> False,
 RotationAction -> "Clip", ImageSize -> 400] & /@ {True, False}]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for answering,still side boarders are not straight lines

Comment: @subbu Why do you say they're not straight?

Comment: @cormullion not straight line in the seance,that boarder lines are not smooth.

Comment: @subbu Does [this demo](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DrawingALineOnADigitalDisplay/) explain why they're not smooth?