# Not getting anti-aliasing with BarChart3D

Tags: graphics3d, plotting

When I put `Antialiasing -> True` in a `BarChart3D`, it doesn't work. Here is the code.

```
BarChart3D[{{1, 2, 3},{2,3,4}}, 
  ChartStyle -> None, 
  ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
  Ticks -> None, 
  Antialiasing -> True]
```

[image: BarChart.png]

How can I apply anti-aliasing to a `BarChart3D`?

Comment: Is antialiasing enabled in Preferences?

Comment: @cormullion Sure:) I've also enabled AA in GPU setting(NVIDIA control panel, for me).

Comment: So it's a platform thing. With more details, perhaps others can help.

Comment: Yes, please add details (version, OS, video card, picture).

Comment: Mathematica8.0, windows7(64bit), GeforceGTX560Ti, http://www5.picturepush.com/photo/a/12911163/640/12911163.png

Comment: Is `Antialiasing` a valid option for `BarChart3D`? (Not at a Mathematica machine at the moment?)

Comment: @user7409 From the documentation, it looks like `Antialiasing` is a `Style` option, not a `BarChart3D` option, so you have to wrap the bar chart in a `Style`.

Comment: @user7409 This appears to be a graphics card issue. With Mathematica9.0, windows7(64bit) and the GTX560Ti I get unexpected behavior.  M9 on Win8 with integrated graphics gives me a slightly crisper output with antialiasing.

Comment: Antialiasing in 3D requires hardware support.  If your hardware (or driver) doesn't support it, here's a workaround: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/200/12

Comment: Is it just `BarChart3D` that has the problem? Do you get antialiasing on other 3D graphics?

Comment: @SimonWoods BarChart3D only :(

Comment: I don't see any anti-aliasing on `Style[Graphics3D[Cuboid[{1, 1, 1}]], Antialiasing -> True]`

Comment: @SEngstrom Do you have it turned on in Preferences -> Appearance -> Graphics?  If moving that slider does nothing then your hardware probably doesn't support it.

Comment: @user7409 It sounds quite unlikely ... you mean that `Plot3D[Sin[x^2 + y^2], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]` *does* have antialiasing?  Or only 2D graphics do?

Comment: Missed the setting (MMA9.0/Ubuntu12.04/nvidia gtx550ti) and 3D plots now snap into anti-aliased form after I stop manipulating them (rotating etc). 2D plots were properly anti-aliased without turning on that setting.

Comment: The option `Antialiasing -> True` is inappropriate for `Graphics3D`. Moving the slider in Preferences > Appearance > Graphics sufficiently to the right should cure this problem.

Comment: This question is answered [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20245/).

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I believe the correct syntax is:

```
BarChart3D[{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}}, ChartStyle -> None, ChartLayout -> "Grid", 
  Ticks -> None, BaseStyle -> Antialiasing -> True]
```

but [as stated above](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25081/no-anti-aliasing-on-barchart3d#comment77631_25081) your hardware must support it.

Comment: Won't work either.
http://www1.picturepush.com/photo/a/12918114/1024/Anonymous/K-20130513-232355.png

Comment: @user7409 do you have anti-aliasing in *any* 3D graphics inside *Mathematica*?

Comment: Sure. Everything's fine except BarChart3D. I've found that the axes are fine. http://www3.picturepush.com/photo/a/12918356/1024/Anonymous/K-20130513-269605.png

Comment: @user7409 would you give me (in the question, because it won't fit in a comment) the output of `Options[BarChart3D]`?

Comment: Using V9.0.1 on OS X, I find `BaseStyle -> Antialiasing -> True` accomplishes nothing if the slider in Preferences > Appearance > Graphics is to the far left. Moving the slider sufficiently to the right adds anti-aliasing even if this option is not set.

Comment: @m_goldberg If you look at the image linked two comments above your you will see that the user *already* has antialiasing enabled and working for *other* 3D graphics; the problem is specific to BarChart3D.  That differentiates this question from the one you have proposed as a duplicate.  Unfortunately he never returned to further attempt to resolve this.

Comment: @m_goldberg If it's a duplicate its a duplicate of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25394/121); I suspect limited hardware/drivers that can't handle AA on transparent graphics, which `BarChart3D` uses.

Comment: FWIW, there is a `GraphicsGroup3DBox` with the setting `Antialiasing -> False` in the `InputForm` of the `BarChart3D` output (V9).  However, it is separate from the main graphics, with no effective content, so I can't see how that could affect the OP.  I cannot reproduce the OP's problem on my machine, so I'm left guessing.