# Anti-aliasing won't work when there is PlotStyle command

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I've found that if there is `PlotStyle` command in the input, anti-aliasing will not work.

However if the `Style` code is `None`, it's OK.

- No style:

[image]

- Style:

[image]

How do I adjust the input to resolve the problem?

Comment: Image for Style->None http://www3.picturepush.com/photo/a/13066756/640/13066756.png

Comment: Are you talking about `Style` or `PlotStyle`?  Please be specific.  If you're talking about `PlotStyle`, have you tried changing anything else than the opacity?  Maybe your video driver auto-disables anti-aliasing for scenes with transparency to improve performance.

Comment: Please edit your question to make this clear then.  `Style` is a built-in symbol which can be applied to graphics as well.

Comment: Thank you for the edit.  This is most likely a limitation of your hardware or drivers (or a problem with how Mathematica uses them).  Unfortunately it is unlikely that you can do much about it.  For exporting anti-aliased graphics, you can try [this solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198/12).  With my previous computer it was simply not possible to have anti-aliasing in 3D graphics.

Comment: Any difference with: `Style[Plot3D[x + y, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.5]], 
 RenderingOptions -> {"Graphics3DRenderingEngine" -> "BSPTree"}]`?