# Make all the lines equally sharp

Tags: graphics

```
Graphics[{
  Line[{{# - 1, -0.5}, {# - 1, 5.5}} & /@ Range[6]],
  Line[{{-0.5, # - 1}, {5.5, # - 1}} & /@ Range[6]]
  }]
```

There are two kinds of lines in this simple picture, some lines look sharp and others look blurry. How can I avoid this effect?

If I zoom in the graphics by dragging the controlled-corner, the blurry effect still exists with different lines.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This seems to be connected to `Antialiasing` (which set to `False`produces crisp lines):

```
g = Graphics[{Line[{{# - 1, -0.5}, {# - 1, 5.5}} & /@ Range[6]], 
    Line[{{-0.5, # - 1}, {5.5, # - 1}} & /@ Range[6]]}];

Grid[{{g, Style[g, Antialiasing -> False]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I thought it was a dupe, and here you are: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14543/131

Comment: Nice detective work!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate the cosmetic glitch but cannot explain why it occurs.
Anyway, here are some options to minimize the effect.

You could use `Gridlines`:

```
Graphics[{}, GridLines -> {Range[6], Range[6]}, PlotRange -> {{1, 6}, {1, 6}},  
PlotRangePadding -> 0.5]
```

[image: gridlines]

---

Or `Thin`:

```
Graphics[{Thin, 
Line[{{# - 1, -0.5}, {# - 1, 5.5}} & /@ Range[6]], 
Line[{{-0.5, # - 1}, {5.5, # - 1}} & /@ Range[6]]}]
```

[image: pic2]

---

Or `Thickness`:

```
Graphics[{Thickness[.001], 
Line[{{# - 1, -0.5}, {# - 1, 5.5}} & /@ Range[6]], 
Line[{{-0.5, # - 1}, {5.5, # - 1}} & /@ Range[6]]}]
```

[image: pic3]

Comment: I get the same result by using your first method, but `Thin` and `Thickness` contribute nothing. Have you changed the opacity in last two methods?

Comment: No opacity changes in the final two pictures. I should mention that I am using a Mac computer with OS X 10.8.5, Mathematica 9.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

```
Graphics[{
  EdgeForm@{Black}, Opacity@0,
  Table[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {i, 5}], {i, 5}],
  Table[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {5, i}], {i, 5}]
  }]
```

[image]