# Why VertexColors decreases the smoothness of lines?

Tags: graphics

```
Show[
 Graphics[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}},VertexColors -> {Opacity[0, Red], Opacity[1, Red], Opacity[1, Red],Opacity[0, Red]}]], 
 Graphics[Circle[{0.5, 0.5}, 0.2]]
 ]

Show[
 Graphics[{Red, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}],
 Graphics[Circle[{0.5, 0.5}, 0.2]]
 ]
```

Where the circle in first one looks bad smoothness. Any method to fix this?
[image]

Comment: related: [Antialiasing of horizontal lines](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14543/125) but `Antialising` trick doesn't work in this case (v9 and v11.3)

Comment: Just as info: This is not happening in my copy of version 11.3 for macOS.

Comment: Related: [(7416)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7416/121)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
Show[
    Graphics[
        Polygon[
            {{0,0},{1,0},{1,1},{0,1}},
            VertexColors->{Opacity[0,Red],Opacity[1,Red],Opacity[1,Red],Opacity[0,Red]}
        ]
    ],
    Graphics[{Antialiasing->True,Circle[{0.5,0.5},0.2]}]
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Two workarounds:

```
Graphics[{Raster[Table[{1, 0, 0, y}, {x, 0, 1, 1/100}, {y, 0, 1, 
     1/100}], {ImageScaled[{0, 0}], ImageScaled[{1, 1}]}], 
  Circle[{.5, .5}, .2]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

```
Overlay[{Graphics[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
  VertexColors -> {Opacity[0, Red], Opacity[1, Red], Opacity[1, Red], Opacity[0, Red]}]], 
  Graphics[Circle[{0.5, 0.5}, 0.2], PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As to the "why": because once you include a `Polygon` with `VertexColors`, the graphics will be rendered by the GPU (the same as 3D graphics).  This means limited support for anti-aliasing which is going to be GPU-dependent.

You can turn on anti-aliasing for such graphics in the preferences, if your GPU supports it.

[image]