# White Edges Around Graphics Elements

Tags: graphics

Using the following code, I am able to generate a grayscale Voronoi diagram:

```
numpts = 12;
pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {numpts, 2}];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]

mps = MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2];
vvv = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[mps], i++,
col = GrayLevel[  RandomReal[{0, 1}]  ] ;
graphicGrain = Graphics[{col, Polygon[mps[[ i ]] [[1]]  ]} ];

AppendTo[vvv, graphicGrain];

]

img = Show[vvv, ImageSize -> 1000, "ShrinkWrap" -> True];
img = ImageCrop[img, {950}]
Export["img_q.pdf", img]
```

[image]

As we can see from the image below, some of the grain boundaries seem to have a white edge going through them

[image]

Is there any way to generate a Voronoi diagram in such a way that these edges are not present? I have looked at similar posts regarding this 'white edge' problem but have not been successful at removing them myself.

Comment: No white edges on 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014) and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680MX 2048 MB.

Comment: Possibly related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1400/removing-unwanted-appearance-of-underlying-mesh  Please mention your OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue appears to be the related to the `Thickness` of the edges of the polygons. It shows up most when adjacent colours are dark. By increasing the thickness of the edges using `Thickness` and setting the colour of the edges to the colour of the polygon using `EdgeForm` you can make the edges overlap slightly and remove the white lines.

I would also use the `Graphics` object for the export to get a better resolution in the PDF file.

I've made a slight refactoring of the code to remove the loop so it is more in Mma style.

```
numpts = 12;
pts = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {numpts, 2}];
mesh = VoronoiMesh[pts, {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];
mps = MeshPrimitives[mesh, 2];

colourDirectives = {#, EdgeForm[#]} & /@ (GrayLevel[RandomReal[{0, 1}]] & /@ 
     Range[First@Dimensions@mps]);
img = Graphics[
   {Thickness[0.02]}~Append~Flatten@Riffle[colourDirectives, mps], ImageSize -> 400]
```

`colourDirectives` gets a list of pairs of `GrayLevel` and `EdgeForm` of that colour for the polygons. These are `Riffle`d with the polygons in `mps` and `Flatten` into a single list for `Graphic`. That list has the `Thickness` `Append`ed to it so all edges are drawn that thickness.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can use `colourDirectives = {#, EdgeForm[#]} & /@ 
   Table[GrayLevel[RandomReal[{0, 1}]], {First@Dimensions@mps}];` as well if that is easier to read when you come back to it later.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed previously this is an artifact of antialiasing by way of transparancy.

- [Antialiasing option behaves weird (polygon edges visible in ContourPlot)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/381/121)
- [Avoiding white lines inside filled area in RegionPlot exported as PDF or PS](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2629/121)

Along the margins the transparency of the overlaid polygons is not complete and the background shows through.  A solution is to turn off [`Antialiasing`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Antialiasing.html), which can be done [inline as a directive](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7417/121) with:

```
Graphics[{col, Antialiasing -> False, Polygon[mps[[i]][[1]]]}]
```

The result:

[image]

However this leaves rough edges between cells.  A better result may be had by eliminating the transparency that causes the problem.  A hackish but effective method is to draw multiple copies of each polygon until the stack is virtually opaque:

```
Show[{vvv, vvv, vvv}]
```

[image]

If rasterization is allowed, or preferred, one can use [`SetAlphaChannel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetAlphaChannel.html) to make the image solid, but for this to be effective one must *also* set `Background -> None` in `Show` or the default white background will be used when the image is flattened, making this ineffectual.

```
SetAlphaChannel[Show[vvv, Background -> None, ImageSize -> 500]] ~ImageCrop~ 450
```

[image]