# Graphics option to suppress lines between adjoining polygons

Tags: graphics, options, polygons

In 10.3.1 there was a `Graphics` option -- it might be a sub-option of `Method` -- which erases the thin line visible at the join between these two `Polygon`s:

```
Graphics[{Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}], Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}]
```

[image: polygons showing line at join]

I presume it is still present in 10.4. Can someone remind me what it is?

Comment: In this case, adding `EdgeForm[Black]` at the beginning fixes it. Not very general, though. `EdgeForm[Opacity[1]]` might be more general.

Comment: Converting to `GraphicsComplex` may also be an option.

Comment: Related, perhaps a duplicate: [(381)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/381/121), [(2629)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2629/121)

Comment: @march Nice solution.  However that's still not really general; consider `Graphics[{Red, EdgeForm[Opacity[1]], Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}], 
  Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}]`

Comment: Related: [80824](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80824)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the option I'm looking for: `Method->"TransparentPolygonMesh"->True`. The documentation for `Graphics` says it should erase the adjoining lines between `Polygon`s. However:

For `Graphics`, `Antialiasing->False` (as a directive) erases the line, as Mr.Wizard says; `Method->"TransparentPolygonMesh"` apparently does nothing.

For `GeoGraphics` (with `GeoBackground->None`), both `Antialiasing->True` and `Method->"TransparentPolygonMesh"->True` erase the line, regardless of the setting of the other.

Since the defaults are `Antialiasing->True` and `Method->"TransparentPolygonMesh"->False`, `Graphics` by default show the lines, but `GeoGraphics` do not.

Answer (score 8):

`Antialiasing -> False` will do it, which surprisingly can be used in-line as a directive:

```
Graphics[{Antialiasing -> False, Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}], 
  Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}]}]
```

Because the multiple-polygon form of `Polygon` (presently?) renders without antialiasing by default this also works:

```
Graphics[{Polygon[{{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}}]}]
```

Reference:

- [Anti-aliasing with the multiple-object form of Polygon?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7416/121)

Comment: never ceases to amaze me...thank you for link also :)

Comment: @ubpdqn Thanks for the kind words.  I do wonder if `RegionUnion` is not a better solution in many cases however.  I hesitate to vote only because it doesn't answer the direct question that was asked.  Then again sometimes indirect answers *are* the best answers.

Comment: I assumed this MWE was for more complex purposes, else you could just use rectangle. It is one of the joys of MMA and this site that there is more than one way to do things and wisdom is in choice including caveat emptor...:)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
pg = {Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}], 
   Polygon[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}}]};
ru = RegionUnion @@ pg;
RegionPlot[ru, PlotStyle -> Yellow, Frame -> False
```

[image]

or

```
BoundaryMesh[DiscretizeRegion@ru, MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> {Black, Thick}, 2 ->Yellow}]
```