# Remove Resolution Limit of Vector Graphics Output

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format

I am currently trying to export an `ArrayPlot` of data in vectorized form as a physically small PDF, in this case 31x256 data points into a final figure size of 180 printer's points.

For larger figure sizes, or fewer rows, the figure exports as I would expect, with rectangular pixels that correspond to the value in a particular cell.

However, below a certain feature size (achieved by either shrinking the `ImageSize` or increasing the number of rows), the output becomes a blurry-looking density plot rather than an exact `ArrayPlot`.

To demonstrate this, I have the following code which serves as a MWE. On MMA 11.1 on Windows 10 (reported screen resolution: 96 DPI), the code results in both a blurry figure in the notebook and a blurry exported figure. On MMA 11.2 on MacOS 10.13 (reported screen resolution: 144), the code results in a clear figure in the notebook but a blurry exported figure.

```
m = RandomReal[{0.0,1.0},{35,50}];
gr = Graphics[Raster[m], ImageSize -> 150, AspectRatio -> 1]
Export[exporDirectory <> "test.pdf",gr]
```

Here is a screenshot of the resulting PDF (blurriness does not change with zooming in to PDF):

[image: Blurry ArrayPlot]

While this is the expected behavior (rectangles remain sharp even when zooming in):

[image: Sharp ArrayPlot]

Increasing the `ImageSize` or reducing the number of rows restores the expected behavior. Changing the number of columns does not seem to have any effect (e.g. 25x50 and 25x500 both export correctly).

I understand that there are limits to what Mathematica can display in the notebook, but AFAIK, these should not apply to a PDF output.

I have tried playing with `Rasterize`, `ImageResolution`, and `RasterSize`, but nothing has changed the output. Unlike [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11273/pdf-exports-of-arrayplots-are-fuzzy-os-x), the problem occurs on both Windows and OS X.

Is there a way to increase the "resolution" of the resulting PDF output?

Comment: With *Mathematica* 11.2.0 on Windows 7 x64 I get PDF without any blurriness: [screenshot from Acrobat 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NBhR.png). May be it is a problem of your PDF renderer? Which PDF viewer do you use?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It's not *just* Mathematica, it's also the PDF viewer. `Raster` is inserted into the PDF as an image. The PDF viewer needs to decide how to up/downsample this image, and often it will use a "blurry" resampler (e.g. bilinear).

Comment: Personally I just replace the `Raster` with a set of `Rectangle`s if I need to make sure that it will render in a sharp way in *all* viewers. (Yes, it's a lot of trouble. It's best to write a utility function once and re-use it.)

Comment: @Szabolcs Please see my answer below. Latest versions of *Mathematica* automatically convert `Raster` into a set of rectangles if the image size is sufficiently large.

Comment: This works fine for me (zoom way in to sharp rectangles) on both 10.1/windows and 11.1/linux.

Answer (score 2):

(Not an answer, just an illustrated comment.)

Note that with low `ImageSize` *Mathematica* exports your `Raster` as a raster image, while with higher `ImageSize` it converts it into a set of vector rectangles. Moreover, the threshold depends on the pixel size of `Raster`. A proof using my [`shortInputForm`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/55545/280) function:

```
Import["http://raw.github.com/AlexeyPopkov/shortInputForm/master/shortInputForm.m"];

m = RandomReal[{0.0, 1.0}, {2, 2}];
gr = Graphics[{Raster[m]}, AspectRatio -> 1];
ImportString[ExportString[Show[gr, ImageSize -> 2], "PDF"], "PDF"][[1]] // shortInputForm
```

> [image: screenshot]

```
ImportString[ExportString[Show[gr, ImageSize -> 20], "PDF"], "PDF"][[1]] // shortInputForm
```

> [image: screenshot]

Related thread:

- [Why do grid marks appear when exporting SVG but not EPS?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/160272/280)