Spurious edges showing between adjacent polygons
Is there a workaround to this problem?:
With EdgeForm[], a sequence of polygons of the form Polygon[{v1, v2,...}] shows edges where as Polygon[{{v1, v2,...}}] with extra braces does not show edges:
Directive[EdgeForm[], Darker@Blue], Polygon[{v1, v2,...}],... (* spurious edges *)
Directive[EdgeForm[], Darker@Blue], Polygon[{{v1, v2,...}}],... (* no edges *)

I think there should be no edges in the first case, and I will call them "spurious edges." Example with full code given below.
When resizing the graphics, sometimes the spurious edges disappear and reappear. When Normal is applied to graphics containing a GraphicsComplex, the first form of polygons, the one with spurious edges, is returned.
Reference: I discovered this while investigating this question:
How to define styles for a mesh based on element index
Full MWE:
Block[{coordinates, incidents},
 coordinates = Tuples[N@Range@3, 2];
 incidents = {
   {{1, 2, 3 + 2, 3 + 1}, {2, 3, 3 + 3, 3 + 2}},
   {{4, 5, 3 + 5, 3 + 4}, {5, 6, 3 + 6, 3 + 5}}};
 GraphicsRow[{
   gr1 = Graphics[{GraphicsComplex[coordinates,
       {Directive[EdgeForm[], Darker@Blue]
        , Polygon[incidents[[1, 1]]], Polygon[incidents[[1, 2]]]
        , Polygon[incidents[[2, 1]]], Polygon[incidents[[2, 2]]]}]
      }, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> 399],
   gr2 = Graphics[{GraphicsComplex[coordinates,
       {Directive[EdgeForm[], Darker@Blue]
        , Polygon[{incidents[[1, 1]]}], Polygon[{incidents[[1, 2]]}]
        , Polygon[{incidents[[2, 1]]}], 
        Polygon[{incidents[[2, 2]]}]}]
      }, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, ImageSize -> 399]
   }]
 ]


There is a thin white edge in the left image (gr1), while the right image (gr2) is solid blue.
This comes up when we apply Normal[] to a graphics containing a GraphicsComplex[] that includes polygons:
Normal[gr2]


Again, is there a workaround to this bug,
especially since it is the result of Normal[]?
Update: My system:
"14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)"

[Reported to WRI, CASE:5145261.]

Weird, if I give the Directive in gr2 any transparency, then the edges go away in gr1. Even Directive[EdgeForm[], Darker@Blue, Opacity[1 - 0.5$MachineEpsilon]]! But if I use Opacity[1], the edges come back. Perhaps the transparency switches to use a different rendering engine? (on MacOS)

A workaround is Style[expr, Antialiasing -> False], or even to use Antialiasing -> False as a local directive. But this could also effect quality elsewhere.

@GregHurst Thanks! Antialiasing -> False works for me too. (I also have a Mac.) I suppose that is an actual answer.  I realized there is a workaround implicit in the question: Add extra braces around the vertex list where needed. A bit tricky to do maybe, if you wish to handle graphics with a mixture of GraphicsComplex and ordinary polygons, and to check the multiple forms of polygons (with holes, etc.).

Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/381/antialiasing-option-behaves-weird-polygon-edges-visible-in-contourplot (Thanks, @Greg, Antialiasing helped me find it.) However, the fix I had in mind in my previous comment does not work.
